# How to delete a song from inside an iPod?

Tags: ipod, ipod-nano

My girlfriend has an iPod Nano (3G) and she asked me how she can delete a song from inside iPod.

I didn't find any option inside the device, is it really like that? Can I delete songs only using iTunes?

Answer (score 7):

Correct, on a stock iPod that is non jail broken, you can only delete music via iTunes.

Comment: If it is allowed by site rules, can you tell me more about jail broken iPod?

Comment: JailBreaking isn't for iPod Nanos.